# WIX Installer Install in Multiple Locations then Patch

Tags: installation, wix

First let me say if this doesn't make sense to somebody please let me know.

Here is my scenario... and I believe it *should* be potentially simple.  Let's say I had a scenario where my Installer installed to:

```
Program Files/MyProduct/Development
```

Also I wanted to have the same installer install to:

```
Program Files/MyProduct/Test
```

Is this possible with WIX?

In addition, how might I go about patching each if so?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to put your finger on  is called multiple instance installers.  I've done a lot of it in InstallShield rather then WiX and Major/Minor upgrades rather then patching.  Yan's done more on the WiX side including writing some blog articles.

But be warned, it's not simple. :-)

[Revisited: Multiple Instance installations and patches](http://ysdevlog.blogspot.com/2011/08/revisited-multiple-instance.html)

Comment: Hey thanks for the response!  So it looks like in order to do this I have to hard code product IDs based on how many installs?  I wouldn't have that information up front as the user could potentially install X number of copies just in different directories.  Make sense?

Comment: Understood.  The reality is you pre-gen X number of instance transforms and assume it'll be enough for 99% of the users or you come up with a more complicated story of a boostrapper (EXE) the generates +1 transform at runtime.  It can be done, but the infrasturcture is a lot higher and I haven't met anyone yet who couldn't be happy enough with the first story.  Even SQL server for example sets a limit of 50 instances per machine.

Comment: Would you write (maybe in C#/WinForms) some kind of wrapper that would allow an end user to easily install multiple instances?  I wouldn't think an end user would need to know about transforms, etc.  Any thoughts there?

Answer (score 0):

Conventionally the `INSTALLDIR` or `INSTALLLOCATION` is a public property which you can set via the command line or bootstapper. E.g.:

```
msiexec /i setup.msi INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\MyProduct\Test"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should allow you to install side-by-side, I would suggest that you are very careful with this approach and should only use this for development purposes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?if $(var.MyApplication.Configuration) = Debug ?>
<?define UpgradeCode = "<INSERT-DEVELOPMENT-GUID-HERE>" ?>
<?else ?>
<?define UpgradeCode = "<INSERT-RELEASE-GUID-HERE>" ?>
<?endif ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*"  Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="SetupProject1" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
```

This approach uses the configuratuion of the referenced project, so for this to work you must have referenced a project (shown above as MyApplication).  This will create an installer with a different Upgrade Code when you compile for Debug.

You then need to deploy in the manner described by @KMoraz.